# How to display a Chinese caption with LaTeX formulas in MATLAB plots?

Tags: matlab, latex

I'm trying to draw a MATLAB plot while using LaTeX formulas in MATLAB R2023a, but I can't display Chinese characters and LaTeX formulas at the same time, my code goes like this:

```matlab
clc; clear; close all;
s=5000000;
x=1:s; y=cos(x);
y=cumsum(y);
figure
plot(x,y,'.')
title('级数$f=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n cosk$','Interpreter','latex')
```

but my plot looks like this:

[image: the plot with Chinese characters and LaTeX]

I want to show them at the same time.

I tried to modify the `mxdom2latex.xsl`:

```latex
<xsl:template match="mscript">
% This LaTeX was auto-generated from MATLAB code.
% To make changes, update the MATLAB code and republish this document.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ctex}    % the only one statement that I added

\sloppy
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
```

But it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab Latex interpreter do not work with CJK characters, period. The best you can do, at the moment, is to mimic the effect using the 'tex' interpreter, e.g.

```
figure
title('级数\it \fontname{Times}f \rm= \Sigma^{n}_{k=1} \itcosk','Interpreter','tex')
```

produces

[image]