# In matlab, How can I display both Chinese characters and LaTeX symbols in a label?

Tags: matlab, label, latex, cjk, chinese-simplified

How to display both Chinese characters and LaTeX symbols in a label?

if I use latex Interpreter, there are some error:

```
close
clear

x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
y = sin(x);

figure;
plot(x, y);

xlabel( '$\text{中文}m_k$', 'Interpreter', 'latex');
```

[image: plot with mixed xlabel]

If I use the TeX interpreter, the symbols do not display in italics, and the font is not the default LaTeX font:

```
close
clear

x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
y = sin(x);

figure;
plot(x, y);

xlabel( '{中文}m_k', 'Interpreter', 'tex');
```

[image]

Comment: It's been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193180/how-to-display-a-chinese-caption-with-latex-formulas-in-matlab-plots)

Comment: the subscript or superscript are not perfect,  expecial the font is not latex default font